# Run background job in Windows powershell - after closing the powershell session

Tags: powershell, window, background-process

I am looking for help with command to run the java app in background
`java -jar app.jar` is the command
Below is the command working till the session is open
`Start-Job -Command {java -jar .\app.jar}`
If i close the powershell terminal session, it is killing job. When i try to list jobs with `Get-Job` nothing is listing and also i observed processing is stopped. Can you please share the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script and have it hidden in the background, you can just run the script like:

powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File ........

or if for whatever reason you want the script initially visible and then hidden afterwards, I think you could put the part of the script you want to keep running after closure in a runspace, as I think even if you close powershell the runspace will keep running, assuming that it has commands to run still.